# Gitlab CI/CD caching cleanup mechanism

Tags: python, caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-venv

I have a simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which duty is to create `venv` && install `requirements.txt` && activate virtual environment in the `before_script`, but this is done only if the `venv` dir doesn't exists. Then in each next stage I want to re-use that cached `venv` which I can do successfully but with a problem between pipelines.

So the main idea is to have a cache that is independent on each pipeline, so for example, 1st time I push to gitlab and it runs this pipeline creating and using the cache, then the second time I push to gitlab I do not want that it would use previously created cache and would start fresh (because for e.g. I have new dependencies), but at the moment in **Example 1** I always get the same cache and it always uses the same `venv`, which is not ideal. While in the **Example 2** I have created a custom `cleanup` stage where I delete the cache, which works then fine as for the next pipeline I create a new `venv` dir and install all the `requirements`, but I get an ugly `WARNING: venv/: no matching files` which I do not want to see in results.

**Custom cleanup cache warning message**

```
....
Restoring cache
00:02
Checking cache for %CI_PIPELINE_ID%-2...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/<>/%25CI_PIPELINE_ID%25-2 
WARNING: venv/bin/python: chmod venv/bin/python: no such file or directory (suppressing repeats) 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:fc14d038d14407498be583a6aa2e27d6b251814e9b004b003ee17bfdc038d5a1 for python:3.9.2-alpine3.12 with digest python@sha256:f092b9adbc7cbc012e9b857899e043af5d4de9ffd01ec32cb12ba38c295752d4 ...
$ python -V
Python 3.9.2
$ ls -la
total 72
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Mar 12 11:41 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Mar 12 11:41 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 Mar 12 11:41 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            41 Mar 12 11:41 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           664 Mar 12 11:41 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            15 Mar 12 11:41 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Mar 12 11:41 app
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           275 Mar 12 11:41 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Mar 12 11:32 venv
$ pwd
/builds/rsimkus/static-flask-website
$ [[ ! -d "venv" ]] && python3.9 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt || source venv/bin/activate
$ echo "removing venv dir for next pipeline"
removing venv dir for next pipeline
$ rm -rf venv
Saving cache for successful job
00:02
Creating cache %CI_PIPELINE_ID%-2...
WARNING: venv/: no matching files                  
Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/<>/%25CI_PIPELINE_ID%25-2 
Created cache
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

So my question: How do I properly create a `cache` for a single pipeline and not worrying that next pipeline will use previous cached `venv`?

And how do you solve the caching issue between different gitlab pipelines?

**Example 1**

```yaml
image: python:3.9.2-alpine3.12

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  key: "%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  paths:
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V
  - ls -la
  - pwd
  -  '[[ ! -d "venv" ]] && python3.9 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt || source venv/bin/activate'

build-app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "building static flask app"

test-code:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running unit tests with pytest module"
    - pytest
```

**Example 2**

```yaml
image: python:3.9.2-alpine3.12

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - cleanup

cache:
  key: "%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  paths:
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V
  - ls -la
  - pwd
  -  '[[ ! -d "venv" ]] && python3.9 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt || source venv/bin/activate'

build-app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "building static flask app"

test-code:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running unit tests with pytest module"
    - pytest

cleanup-venv:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo "removing venv dir for next pipeline"
    - rm -rf venv
```

Any tips, tricks or comments are appreciated.

**UPDATE 2021-03-15**

I have updated .yml file with correct syntax, from `%CI_PIPELINE_ID%` to `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` which did the trick and `venv` is independed across pipelines. But now I get ugly `FATAL: file does not exist` error in the first stage `build`

*Updated .yml*

```
image: python:3.9.2-alpine3.12

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
  paths:
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V
  - ls -la
  - pwd
  -  '[[ ! -d "venv" ]] && python3.9 -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt || source venv/bin/activate'

build-app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "building static flask app"

test-code:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running unit tests with pytest module"
    - pytest
```

*log of build stage*

```
Created fresh repository.
Checking out eef91fb7 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:00
Checking cache for 270417733-2...
FATAL: file does not exist                         
Failed to extract cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
```

Any ideas why now I get this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux shell/docker executors use `key: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID"`

If you are using a requirements file with pinned versions, using `$key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"` would make more sense, since your requirements will only change in the commit ref changes. This will allow MR pipelines and branch pipelines with the same commit ref to share the cache.

`%VAR%` syntax is for Windows batch.

Comment: Hi, ok one issue was that I misunderstood how to use `CI_PIPELINE_ID`, I used it like `% CI_PIPELINE_ID%` where it had to be as you shown `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` which did the trick. But now I get the error at the first stage (see updated example and log in Q), why I get this `FATAL: file does not exist` at the first stage, for the next stage it's ok?

Comment: @simkusr if it persists, try clearing your runner cache on the pipelines page, but that's normal behavior when the cache does not exist and is created for the first time, I believe.

Comment: After clearing cache in the UI, the same fatal error message is provided. But that is a strange behaviour as if I say that I want that I use `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` as key for cache, shouldn't it understand that on initial stage it will not exist as each pipeline will have different ID which makes me wonder that maybe there is some other way or additional step I need to perform so that I would not see this fatal error? I have also tried with `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`, the same fatal error is given. @sytech is there any other way I could do so I would not see this fatal error?

Comment: This is I guess secondary question and not related to the original one. I will accept it as it helped to resolve the main issue here. Thank you @sytech for this one!